# collections in spring not working

Tags: java, xml, spring

I am new to spring framework and i am trying to perform collections concept in spring.when i am running my bellow code it shows the bellow error message.

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'classname' of bean class [com.collections.subject]: Bean property 'classname' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

i tried to solve this but i can't find where i am wrong. can any one help me to fix this.

main.java

```
package com.collections;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

public class main {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Resource res=new ClassPathResource("/config/applicationcontext.xml");
        BeanFactory bf=new XmlBeanFactory(res);

        subject sobj=(subject) bf.getBean("b1");
        sobj.show();
    }

}
```

subject.java

```
package com.collections;
import java.util.*;

public class subject {
    private String classname;
    private int id;
    private List<String> sub;

    public String getname()
    {
        return classname;
    }

    public void setname(String classname)
    {
        this.classname=classname;
    }




    public int getid()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public List<String> getlist()
    {
        return sub;
    }



    public void setid(int id){

        this.id=id;
    }
    public void setlist(List<String> sub)
    {
        this.sub=sub;
    }

    public void show()
    {
        System.out.println("classname is:"+classname);
        System.out.println("id is:"+id);
        System.out.println("available subjects are:");

        Iterator<String> itr=sub.iterator();

        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(itr.next());

        }
    }
}
```

applicationcontext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans  
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  

 <bean id="b1" class="com.collections.subject">
 <property name="classname" value="First"></property>
 <property name="id" value="12"></property>
 <property name="sub">
 <list>
 <value>tamil</value>
 <value>english</value>
 <value>maths</value>
 <value>science</value>
 <value>social</value>
 </list>
 </property>

  </bean>
  </beans>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't go anywhere if you don't respect the Java and Java Bean naming conventions:

- Classes start with an uppercase letter
- For a property named foo, the getters/setters are `getFoo()` and `setFoo()`. Not `getfoo()` and `setfoo()`. The name of the field used to hold the property value is completely irrelevant. What matters is the name of the getter/setter.

You tried to use XML to set the property classname of your bean:

So Spring will look for a method `setClassname()`. There isn't any, hence the error message.

Answer (score 0):

check by replacing

```
public void setlist(List<String> sub)
{
    this.sub=sub;
}
```

with

```
   public void setSub(List<String> sub)
{
    this.sub=sub;
}
```